# Who is the mother-in-law of Surya?

Tags: surya, vishwakarma

I have heard stories of Surya getting married to Vishwakarma's daughter but I don't know the name of Vishwakarma's wife. Who was she and what is her story?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your enquiry is about the wife of Vishwakarma also called as Tvaṣṭā (त्वष्टा). The puranas is  giving us the name of  wife of  Vishwakarma. one prominent and definite among them is **Virocanā (विरोचना).**

---

In [**Vayu Purana**](https://archive.org/stream/VayuPuranaG.V.TagarePart2/Vayu%20Purana%20-%20G.V.Tagare%20-%20Part%202#page/n199) - Book 2 -Chapter 22  its mentioned that Virocanā   was  Praladas daughter and sister of Vairocana (son of  Prahlada) was the wife of Tvashta , the next few shlokas also mention Surya getting married to Vishwakarma's daughter  Samjana. .

> प्रह्लादी विश्रुता **तस्य त्वष्टुः पत्नी विरोचना**। 
>    विरोचनस्य भगिनी
>   माता त्रिशिरसस्तु सा ।। Vayu Purana 2.22.19 ।।
>
> 19 Tvastrs wife was the famous daughter of Prahlada and the sister  of
>   Virocana and the mother of Trisiras.

Here in above verse its mentioned that very clearly .

---

> सुरेणुरिति विख्याता स्वसा
>   तस्य यवीयसी।
>    त्वाष्ट्री सा सवितुर्भार्य्या पुनः संज्ञेति विश्रुता
>   ।।2.22.21।।
>
> 21 His younger sister , the daughter of Tvastr (originally) famous by 
>   the name of Surenu became the wife of the Sun and is well known as
>   Samjhana.

---

The above is also confirmed from [**Brahmanda Purana**](https://archive.org/stream/BrahmandaPurana_37/BrahmandaPurana-G.v.tagare-Part3#page/n77) -Part 3 - Chapter 59 - Birth Of Vaivasvata - 2.3.59 .

> 19 Virocana  , famous as the daughter of Prahlada was the wife of
>   Tvastr . She was the sister of  [**Virocana**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virochana) and mother of
>   Trisiras.

---

[**Srimad Bhagavata Purana**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/5/15/14-15) - Skanda 5- Chapter 15- Verse 15 is also giving us the name of wife of Tvasta aka Vishwakarma as Virocana.

> ष्टाजनिष्ट त्वष्टुर्विरोचनायां विरजो विरजस्य || SB 5.15.15||
>
> Bhauvana begot a son named Tvashta. In the womb of his wife Virocana,
>   Tvashta begot a son named Viraja.

---

So from above three accounts we can say that Virocanā (विरोचना) was the wife of  Tvashta , was the mother-in-law-of-surya. Also note that there are two similar english names here with same spelling but different pronunciations  1)  Virochana (Sanskrit: विरोचन) and 2 ) Virocanā (विरोचना) ,sister of Virochana.

---

Below is screenshot of Vayu purana verses.

[image: Vayu Purana 2.22.19]

Comment: I have a question from the snapshot you shared - does this mean the Maya Danav was son of Vishwakarma and brother of Sangya?

Comment: The link given in the above answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virochana is about  grandson of Hiranyakashipu, son of Prahlada, doesn't state it's a female wife of Viswakarma anywhere.

Comment: Found another instance in purana that says "Prahlada‘s son was Virochana and Virochana‘s son was Vali. Vali was defeated by Vishnu in his vamana (dwarf) incarnation. Vali had a son named Vana."

Comment: @Just_Do_It I have provided the link to separate two virochanas , the link is to show that who is male virochana is .

Comment: @AmritDhara - Brahmanda purana is shading some light on this issue , its said there that this maya was actually Vishvakarma himself , but that passage according to translator is defective.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I feel that this lady could be the wife of Tvashtri but this Tvashtra may not be Vishwakarma rather is the son of Vishwakarma. Check this link from Vishnu Puran - http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp050.htm and search for yogasiddha

Answer (score 5):

Well not really sure about the story but Viśvakarmā had a wife named Ākṛtī.

Citing from [SB 6.6.15](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/6/15):

> From Āṅgirasī, the wife of the Vasu named Vāstu, was born the great
>   architect Viśvakarmā. **Viśvakarmā became the husband of Ākṛtī**, from
>   whom the Manu named Cākṣuṣa was born. The sons of Manu were known as
>   the Viśvadevas and Sādhyas.

Found another reference [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vishvakarma):

> **Viśvakarmā (विश्वकर्मा)**.—A Prajāpati. His daughter Barhiṣmatī was the
>   wife of Priyavrata.1 A son of Vāstu and Āngirasī; **wife was Kṛti
>   (Akṛti, Bhāgavata-purāṇa)**. Father of Manu Cākṣuṣa.2 The divine
>   architect skilled in making weapons. Made vajra of Dadhīci's body and
>   built Indra's abode and erected Sutalam.3 Fought with Maya in Devāsura
>   war. **Two more daughters of his were Samjñā and Chāyā who were married
>   to the Sun god**.4 Was ordered by Kṛṣṇa to build a city for the
>   Pāṇḍavas;5 built Garuḍa's abode;6 an author on architecture;7 father
>   of four sons; originator of all śilpas, arts and crafts;8 presented
>   Śrī with jewels.

Comment: Actually the name of the wife of Tvasta mentioned in the verse is Kruti  and not Akriti. The translation is not proper see- विश्वकर्माकृतीपतिः - viśvakarmākṛtī-patiḥ

Comment: Thank you but this lady does not seem to be the mother of Surya's wife.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar `Visvakarmakritipatih` can also be divide as `Visvakarma`+`Akriti`+`Patih`.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Yes you are right , but Gita Press translation is mentioning the kriti word. And the "a" is already used for vishvakarma in this case. SO its more likely that its kriti than akriti.